# Waterline: Create or update a populate record

Tags: sails.js, waterline

My question is basic but I can not find an answer in the documentation. I have two models: 'Person' and 'Location' being associated One-to-one. **I want to create or update 'populated child records' in the Location collection.**

```
 let person = await Person.findOne({ phone: inputs.phone }).populate('reside');
```

Well return

```
{ reside: [],
createdAt: 1540081110195,
updatedAt: 1540331824622,
id: '5bcbc5d609618e2cfbe64883',
phone: '+42424242',}
```

**I want to create new location record (when they do not exist) or update if their exist.** I try

```
let location = await Location.update({ id: person.reside.id })
.set({city: inputs.city,
    street: inputs.street,
  }).fetch;
```

But it does not work when no record has been created yet.

model/Person.js

```
phone: {
  type: 'string',
  unique: true,
},
reside: {
  collection:'location',
  via: 'owner'
},
```

models/Location.js

```
city: { type: 'string' },
street: { type: 'string' },
owner:{
  model:'person',
  unique: true
}
```

I use action2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/records#?modifying-populated-values) methods [.addToCollection()](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/add-to-collection), [.removeFromCollection()](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/remove-from-collection), or [.replaceCollection()](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/replace-collection) to modify the populated values of a particular record or set of records. It does not seem to be the most appropriate place in the doc to talk about it